# How to develop iOS app just like AppStore's searching function?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uisearchbar

I want to develop a simple dictionary application which is like the Search tab of AppStore on iPhone:

1. The 1st screen have a SeachBar on top, the bottom is "History words" (such as "Trending Searches" on AppStore).

[image][image]

When user touches the SearchBar, the bottom view is gray. Touching the gray area to leave the Seach text-box and my user is able to click on one of history words.

2. If he/she types on SearchBar, the suggestion words list appears and he/she can click a word to see its definition with the SearchBar containing the word there (I don't want my users having to go to 2nd view to see word's definition because if so, they must click Back button to touch and type on Seach text-box. It's likely that, my application has only 1 ViewController).

[image][image]

I know how to work with SearchBar and TableView to display the suggestion words list but don't know what to do to implement other things:

- Make a view gray; touching on the gray area to leave the Search text-box
- Hide the suggestion words list (TableView) -> user can see "History words" again
- Keep the SearchBar -> user can type immediately to search other word when he/she is seeing current word definition

Thanks for reading and please show me some keywords, clues to solve three issues above.

Many thanks!

Comment: Too broad. Please just pick _one_ thing you don't know and ask about it.

Comment: "Make a view gray; touching on the gray area to leave the Search text-box" --> display modal controller with ``UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext`` and appropriate opacity. ``Keep the SearchBar`` add it to the navigation bar, probably (and use navigation controller).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UISearchController` to create a page like you wanted.

It has `dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation` property to make a backgroundView gray when user is typing.

It has `- (instancetype)initWithSearchResultsController:(UIViewController *)searchResultsController` method. You can initialize the `UISearchController` with resultsController. For results you can do whatever you want.

Lastly, you can set a custom view to see "History words" to UISearchController

Comment: Thank you, Candost Dagdeviren. With your help, I've successfully implemented the history words list and the suggestion words list. But I dont know how to implement the word's definition view so that when user click a word on the result table, he/she will see the word's definition view with the search bar on top (pls see picture 4 above). If he/she touches the search bar, the suggestion words list appear again.